# Convert string to double when there are thousands

Tags: c#, parsing, double

i'm trying to convert string to double (and then to int) but it raises an exception. My program is old and I'm not sure if that's the case.
When i test it on Visual Studio 2017, it seems to work?

```
   string line = "11-03-1-01   |   1 | 5 000,00|1054 |P:1|KP:|RB:"; 

    private static int GetCount(string line)
    {
        var splittedLine = line.Split('|');
        var lineWithReplacedDot = splittedLine[2].Replace('.', ',');
        var lineWithSpacesRemoved = lineWithReplacedDot.Replace(" ", "");
        var additionalSpacesRemoved = lineWithSpacesRemoved.Trim();
        var parsedToDouble = Double.Parse(additionalSpacesRemoved);
        var parsedToInteger = (int)parsedToDouble;

        return parsedToInteger;

    }
```

When I do it on my old program it raises Format Exception when trying to execute Double.Parse(additionalSpacesRemoved).
It seems that it doesn't remove the space between 5 and 000.

I've also tried Convert.ToDouble(additionalSpacesRemoved) but it didn't help. Are there any other ways?

I would like to achieve "5000" as a result.

Comment: What do you expect `k` to be? i.e. what are you trying to do?

Comment: k should be int of a value 5000

Comment: So you want to get the third item as an `int` separated by `|`?

Comment: I've edited the post, I hope it's more helpful

Comment: Not only thousands but also spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to get the third string separated by `|` as an `int`.

Your code is almost right. You just reversed the order of the arguments `'.', ','`. They should be `',', '.'`. The character you want to replace goes first. Here's some working code:

```
private static int GetCount(string line)
{
    return (int)Convert.ToDouble(
        line.Split('|')[2]
            .Replace(" ", "")
            .Replace(',', '.'));
}
```

Comment: It still throws FormatExeption. I'm not sure what .net version it is. It's an old program that we can edit only via Visual Studio 2008. Perhaps there is something there  that is not supported?

Comment: Is it to do with the locale the program is running under? Can you step through and see what the string `additionalSpacesRemoved` actually contains?

Comment: It contains "5 000,00" so it ignores all that removing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string line = "11-03-1-01   |   1 | 5 000,00|1054 |P:1|KP:|RB:";
    Debug.WriteLine(GetCount(line));
    // 5000
}

public static int GetCount(string line)
{
    var parts = line.Split('|');
    var text = parts[2].Trim();

    var style = new NumberFormatInfo()
    {
        NumberDecimalSeparator=",",
        NumberGroupSeparator=" "
    };

    if (decimal.TryParse(text,
        NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
        style, out decimal result))
    {
        return (int)result;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "decimal does not contain a definition for TryParse"

Comment: @Lucky - it does, since I tried the code in VS2017 before posting.

Comment: I believe you. I just have an old program which runs in VS2008 and it seems that some options are not availalble

Comment: You might want to try `float.TryParse()` or `double.TryParse()` with the `NumerStyles` option then.